# SmsRetrieverHelper SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17006 null firebase phone auth

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have this erro with firebase auth phone confirmation I traid change the divice and change number and add test phone number and I add SHA-1 and SHA-256 put nothing hapend all I change doesn't work, so i need help please and thanks:
[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17006 null
OR
[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17010 null

[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17006 null
I tray every thing in net.